# How to get previous quarter (that occurs in the previous year) from Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have the following formula which returns me the current quarter of the year. However, I would like to retrieve the quarter of a month, which happens to be from the previous year (2020) as we are currently only in Q1 of 2021.

How do I express my results as **Q1-21** and **Q4-20** to give an indication of the year which the quarter falls under?

My formula to retrieve the quarter from a given month is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=4,MONTH(C4)<7),"Q2",IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=7,MONTH(C4)<10),"Q3",IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=10),"Q4",IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=1,MONTH(C4)<4),"Q1"))))
```

[image]

[image]

Kindly advice if you have any suggestion.
Thanks in advance!

**Regards**

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

You can use `CONCATENATE` to include the year:

```
=CONCATENATE(*your formula*, "-", TEXT(C4,"YY"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Excel365` then try `XMatch()` function.

```
 ="Q"&XMATCH(MONTH(A1),{3,6,9,12},1)&"-"&TEXT(A1,"yy")
```

You can use `CONCAT()` in this way-

```
=CONCAT("Q",XMATCH(MONTH(A1),{3,6,9,12},1),"-",TEXT(A1,"yy"))
```

[image]

> Edit:

For current quarter use-

```
="Q"&XMATCH(MONTH(TODAY()),{3,6,9,12},1)&"-"&TEXT(A1,"yy")
```

For previous quarter use

```
="Q"&XMATCH(MONTH(TODAY()),{3,6,9,12},1)&"-"&TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),"yy")
```

Comment: Hi Harun, thanks so much! I found an alternative - `="Q"&IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=4,MONTH(C4)<7),2,IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=7,MONTH(C4)<10),3,IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=10),4,IF(AND(MONTH(C4)>=1,MONTH(C4)<4),1))))&"-"&TEXT(YEAR(C4),"yy")` but this gives **Q1-05** when it is supposed to return **Q1-21** - not sure why it is so..

Comment: Use `=TEXT(C4,"yy")` instead `TEXT(YEAR(C4),"yy")` last part of formula.

Comment: Thanks it works! Pardon me but if i want to use a formula to compute the **month of previous quarter** - how can it be done? I tried `=TEXT(EOMONTH(C3, -4),"mmm-yy")` but this is simply subtracting 4 months from the current month which does not work well

Comment: @Rosellx I would suggest you to accept this answer to close the thread then ask a separate question. That would be better.